# How do I calculate the Jacobian matrix $Dh(x)$ of $h:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m, x\mapsto f(x,g(x)) $ with $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, jacobian

$U\subset \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m$, $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $W\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ are open sets with $V\times W \subset U$.

Let the functions $g:V\rightarrow W$ and
$f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m,x\mapsto f(x,y)$ be continuously differentiable.

Now I want to use the chain rule for multiple variables to calculate the Jacobian matrix $Dh(x)$ of $h:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m, x\mapsto f(x,g(x)) $, but I have problems with it.

Notation:
$\partial_{x_i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i};\, 
f_i(x,g(x))=f_i(x_1,...,x_n,g_1(x),...,g_m(x))$

$$Dh(x)=\begin{pmatrix} \partial_{x_1}(h_1(x))&... &\partial_{x_n}(h_1(x))\\ \vdots& &\vdots \\ \partial_ {x_1}(h_m(x))&... &\partial_{x_n}(h_m(x))\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \partial_{x_1}f_1(x,g(x)) &... &\partial_{x_n}f_1(x,g(x))\\ \vdots& &\vdots \\ \partial_{x_1}f_m(x,g(x))&... &\partial_{ x_n}f_m(x,g(x))\end{pmatrix}$$

How can I calculate(?):
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}f_i(x,g(x))=\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}f_i(x_1,...,x_n,g_1(x),. ..,g_m(x))=?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General rule for finding partial derivative of composition.**
Let $z=g(y^1,\dots,y^n)$ be a real-valued function of the real variables $y^1,\dots,y^n$, each of which in turn is a function $y^j=f^j(x^1,\dots,x^m)\ (j=1,\dots,n)$ of the variables $x^1,\dots,x^m$. Assuming that the functions $g$ and $f^j$ are differentiable $(j=1,\dots,n)$, we can find the partial derivative $\dfrac{\partial (g\circ f)}{\partial x^i}(x)$ of the composition of the mapping $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to \mathbb{R}$.

$$\partial _i(g\circ f)(x)=\partial_jg(f(x))\cdot \partial _if^{j}(x),$$ or in notation that shows more detail
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x^i}(x)=\frac{\partial(g\circ f)}{\partial x^i}(x^1,\dots,x^m)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial y^1}\cdot \frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^i}+\dots+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y^n}\cdot \frac{\partial y^n}{\partial x^i}=$$
$$=\partial_1g(f(x))\cdot \partial_i f^1(x)+\dots+\partial_ng(f(x))\cdot \partial_i f^n(x).$$

*Our problem.* For concreteness let's compute the following partial derivative (here I am using a bit different notation):  $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}f^1(x^1,\dots,x^n,g^1(x),\dots, g^m(x))=$$
$$=\partial_1 f^1\cdot (x^1)'_1+\dots+\partial_n f^1\cdot (x^n)'_1+\partial_{n+1}f^1 \cdot \partial_1g^1+\dots+\partial_{n+m}f^1 \cdot \partial_1g^m=$$
$$=\partial_1 f^1+\partial_{n+1}f^1 \cdot \partial_1g^1+\dots+\partial_{n+m}f^1 \cdot \partial_1g^m.$$

Answer (score 1):

Writing $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m,x\mapsto f(x,y)$  is not correct. The function $f$ is defined on $U$, thus it is a function $z \mapsto f(z)$ where $z = (x,y) \in U$ with $x \in \mathbb R^n, y \in \mathbb R^m$.

Define
$$\phi : V \to U, \phi(x) = (x,g(x)).$$
This function is continuously differentiable because its coordinate functions
$$\phi_i(x) = \begin{cases} x_i & i = 1,\ldots,n \\ g_{n-i}(x) & i = n+1,\ldots, n+m \end{cases} $$
are continuously differentiable. Its Jacobian is
$$D\phi(x) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots& & & \vdots \\ 0 & \ldots & 0 & 1 \\
\partial_{x_1}g_1(x)&... & & \partial_{x_n}g_1(x) \\
\vdots& & & \vdots \\ 
\partial_{x_1}g_m(x)&... & & \partial_{x_n}g_m(x) \end{pmatrix}$$

We have $h = f \circ \phi$, thus $Dh(x) = Df(\phi(x))D\phi(x)$. Since
$$Df(z) = \begin{pmatrix} \partial_{x_1}f_1(z)&... & \partial_{x_n}f_1(z) & \partial_{y_1}f_1(z) & \ldots \partial_{y_m}f_1(z)\\
\vdots& & & \vdots \\ 
 \partial_{x_1}f_m(z)&... & \partial_{x_n}f_m(z) & \partial_{y_1}f_m(z) & \ldots \partial_{y_m}f_m(z) \end{pmatrix}$$
we get $Dh(x) = (a_{ij})$ which is an $(m \times n)$-matrix with
$$a_{ij} =  \partial_{x_j}f_i(x,g(x))+ \sum_{k=1}^m\partial_{y_k}f_i(x,g(x))\partial_{x_j}g_k(x) .$$